npm install angular/cli isnt working - seems stuck midway, no log, no error regarding why it is stuck
Can anyone help me with an issue I have during npm install @angular/cli
Below are the details
Command I am running: npm install -g @angular/cli 
What I am seeing: the install starts pulls some packages then gets stuck at one point, I waited for few hours for it to finish but it never does anything after that point. Here is where it gets stuck (got this when running above command with --verbose)

Alternatives I tried:
@angular/cli@latest 
@angular/cli@specificversion(16/15 etc.) 
restarted machine 
uninstalled/reinstalled node 
checked PATH variable is there 
Run the command as administrator, in powershell, nodejs command prompt, windows command prompt, VS Code terminal, but gets stuck at this point everywhere
I also tried running it after npm cache clean --force

Did you try npm install --force or npm install --force --legacy-peer-deps?

I tried that, that did not work. The issue was with the registry URL, I posted an answer for anyone facing similar issue in the future. @SrikarPhaniKumarM

I figured out the issue myself.
Posting it here as an answer for anyone who might run into this issue in the future.
I had to open .npmrc file with notepad, and update the URL that is set as the default npm registry URL. the URL was set to http://registry.npmjs.org and I changed it to https://registry.npmjs.org
